# URL Redirect and Append #Hashtag

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, redirect, http-status-code-301, dreamhost

My client has gone through a rebrand and has changed their primary URL. I need to redirect all traffic that visits old URLs and send them to the same page on the new URL and ideally append a #hashtag... the hashtag will trigger an overlay explaining the redirect. Both sites are on the same Drupal codebase and thus use the same .htaccess file.

So if someone visits:
http://oldsite.com/abc/def

They should be redirected to:
http://newsite.com/abc/def/#hashtag

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ¿`hashtag` is a fixed string or it is a variable? If so, is missing in the incoming URL. If not, ¿where is that parameter and how is supposed to be captured? The `#` anchor can be passed to the mapped URL but it will have no effect as it won't be processed after a redirect. It would be better to replace it with a folder name or even a query. i.e. `?key=val`. But the requested URL MUST hold it, because it is impossible to guess it.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?
Though I'm no expert when it comes to htaccess trickery.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.newdomain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1/#hashtag [R=301,L]
```